# Put Y-Axis along x=0 line in Bokeh figure

Tags: bokeh

I would like to have my y-axis go right up through the x=0 line in my figure, rather than have it on the left side.  Is there an easy way to achieve this with Bokeh?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently not available in Bokeh, as of `0.12.1`. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/113) for this feature.

Have seen someone visually faking it using spans when replicating [this infographic](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/steph-curry-trails-shaun-livingston-in-the-nba-finals-mvp-race/) - but note labels still off to the left.

Here's the mailing list discussion: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topicsearchin/bokeh/fivethirtyeight/bokeh/_dKphJePDwg

Answer (score 2):

I was attempting to do this and it looks like there is now a solution to this. You can set the `figure.yaxis.fixed_location` attribute to zero.

As an explicit example using bokeh 1.0.4:

```
# ... bokeh imports

p = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.patch([-1,0,1], [-1,1,0.5], alpha=0.5)
p.yaxis.fixed_location = 0
show(p)
```

returns the figure:

[image: bokeh_central_yaxis]

You can also do this for the x-axis or both.